# Selection of records through a join table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :presentations
  has_many :galleries, :through => :presentations
end

class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :presentations
  has_many :collections, :through => :presentations
end

class Presentation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :gallery 
end
```

How do I get all the collections that **do not** belong to a given gallery?

My SQL knowledge is only rudimentary. I also want to let Rails (2.3) do the work without using explicitly a SQL expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, you technically have to write some SQL (where clause)...

```
gallery_to_exclude = Gallery.first
Collection.find(:all,
  :include => :presentations,
  :conditions => ['presentations.gallery_id IS NULL OR presentations.gallery_id != ?',
                   gallery_to_exclude.id])
```

If you want to use [Searchlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic), you can avoid this, though:

```
Collection.presentations_gallery_id_is_not(gallery_to_exclude.id).all
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But only for collections that have a gallery. What about the collections that have no gallery? (collection.galleries.length == 0)

Comment: I edited the above to show collections without galleries. (the #find, not the searchlogic method)